# How do I remove NA values from a stacked barplot using ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, na

I need a bit of help getting the NA values out of my data, as they keep showing up in my barplots as grey in the bottom of all my categories as well as in the legend. I'm trying to compare 2 categorical variables. Here's my code so far:

```
p <- ggplot(data=ndes, aes(x=vaccines, fill=votechoice)) + geom_bar(position="stack") + scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) + labs(title="Approval of Vaccines v. Preferred Candidate", x="Vaccine Approval")
p <- p+guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Preferred Candidate"))
p
```

Is there anything that I could improve on to make the NA values not appear in my data?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to visualize without example data but maybe you can try the following:

```
ndes <- ndes %>%
na.omit(vaccines)

p <- ggplot(data=ndes, aes(x=vaccines, fill=votechoice)) + geom_bar(position="stack") + scale_x_discrete(na.translate = FALSE) + labs(title="Approval of Vaccines v. Preferred Candidate", x="Vaccine Approval")
p <- p+guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Preferred Candidate"))
p
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! All I needed was the %>% and it worked! Thank you so much